# Eulerian polynomial from Bruhat interval - h* of something?

Tags: co.combinatorics, polynomials, convex-polytopes, permutations

Let $\sigma \in S_n$ be a fixed permutation.
Consider the polynomial
$$
P_{\sigma}(t) = \sum_{\substack{\pi \in S_n \\ \pi \leq \sigma}} t^{\textrm{des}(\pi)}
$$
where $\leq$ denotes [Bruhat order](http://symmetricfunctions.com/preliminaries.htm#bruhatOrder), and $\textrm{des}(\pi)$ denotes descents.

**Q:** Is $P_{\sigma}(t)$ the $h^*$-polynomial of some polytope (depending on $\sigma$)?

We know that the answer is yes when $\sigma$ is the top element in Bruhat order,
since then $P_{\sigma}(t)$ is a classical Eulerian polynomial.

Comment: One of these polynomials is $1+6t+t^2$, which I believe rules out h*-polynomials of order polytopes....

Comment: You could ask either for $h^*$-polynomial of a lattice polytope or for $h$-polynomial of a simplicial polytope, since the classical Eulerian polynomial is both (for the hypercube and the dual of the permutohedron).